# Let $u_1 = 1, u_2 = 1, u_3 = 1$ and $u_{n+3} = \frac{1+u_{n+1} u_{n+2} }{u_n}$. Prove that $u_n$ is integer for all $n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $u_1 = 1, u_2 = 1, u_3 = 1$ and $u_{n+3} = \dfrac{1+u_{n+1} u_{n+2} }{u_n},\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$.

Prove that $u_n \in \mathbb{N},\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$.

I thought this one was easy if I used induction method, but it wasn't. Could you give me a hint? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: A more general case is solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/341877/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence is [OEIS A005246](http://oeis.org/A005246), which begins 
$$1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 11, 26, 41, 97, 153, 362, 571, 1351,\\
 2131, 5042, 7953, 18817, 29681, 70226, 110771, 262087, \\
413403, 978122, 1542841, 3650401, 5757961,\\ 13623482, 21489003, 50843527$$

The first comment is that for $n \ge 4$ we have $a(n)=4a(n-2)-a(n-4)$ which is clearly an integer.  Can you justify that?  A search for $5042, 7953, 18817$ turns this up even if you don't know OEIS.

Comment: Thank you for the hint and a useful page :D